# What profiling mechanism available for a spring boot app deployed in azure app services?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, profiling, azure-application-insights

What profiling mechanism available for a spring boot app deployed in azure app services. We have application insight integrated and it is showing profile now option on the application insight performance page it is either not completing sometime or sometime not showing any results

Comment: "on the application insight performance page it is either not completing sometime or sometime not showing any results" - a couple screenshot with examples would help here to better understand the issue..

Answer (score 0):

While your question lacks some details (example/screenshot) when you say

> on the application insight performance page it is either not
> completing sometime or sometime not showing any results

but firstly, I hope you have followed [Configure a Spring Boot Initializer app to use Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-java-applicationinsights). I understand that the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler) lacks clarity on profiling Java application, but you might want to look at the blog post [Azure App Service Java Profiler](https://www.cloudmatter.io/post/azure-app-service-java-profiler).

Additionally, for end-to-end correlation tracing in your sprint boot app, set the below in your `application.properties`.

```
azure.application-insights.web.enable-W3C=true
```

For details on correlation, refer [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers-using-w3c-tracecontext).